# Nginx can't load CSS Files

Tags: php, css, nginx, debian

Somehow nginx can't load CSS files and result website showing with no CSS.

In Firefox I got those warning:

> The stylesheet http://192.168.1.10:6000/templates/main/css/layout.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
>
> The stylesheet http://192.168.1.10:6000/templates/main/css/jqevent.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
>
> The stylesheet http://192.168.1.10:6000/templates/main/css/crud.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

**Nginx Conf**

```
user  root;

http {

    include       /home/school/webapp/nginx/conf/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    server {
        listen 6000;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /home/school/webapp/wwwdir/;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573489/nginx-failing-to-load-css-and-js-files-mime-type-error

Comment: no luck , i already spent 3 days trying to solve it and reading... i also visited that thread but didnt succeed yet...

Comment: but is the nginx conf you provided complete? because if it is, I don't see any css specific conf.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files ----- This is similar to your case .....you can also try changing your default type as well....to **/etc/nginx/mime.types** from **application/octet-stream;**

Comment: @Bogdan , why i should specific css conf ? . sagarthapa , i tried no luck...

Comment: Because it is the css files that are sent with the wrong html header, so just like the link explains, you force the header for your css files.

Comment: i dont use default.conf ?  i only use nginx.conf.. , i have added location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
} . but still no css affected.. , in all my programming years i never faced a problem with that kind sincerely now nearly 5 days and still not solved...

Comment: Finally problem fixed it was a rewrite url line which caused the issue... thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You should include mime types in your nginx.conf. See default nginx.conf here : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Simply add below line include in location /

include    conf/mime.types;