# Springboot: Swagger UI format is not displayed properly in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, swagger

I have a simple spring boot application with two controllers echo-controller and trac-controller. I wanted to have a api documentation for these services end points.  I am trying to do with **swagger ui 2.6.1** with spring boot version: **1.5.2.RELEASE**

#### In the `pom.xml` file i have these dependencies added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>        
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Below is my echo controller

        @Controller
    public class EchoController {   

        @ApiOperation(value="Test Echo Service",response=ResponseEntity.class)
        @ApiResponses(value={
           @ApiResponse(code=200,message="Test Echo Service Retrieved",response=ResponseEntity.class),
           @ApiResponse(code=500,message="Internal Server Error"),
           @ApiResponse(code=404,message="Test Echo Service not found")
        })
        @RequestMapping(value = "/echo/{any}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String echo(@PathVariable("any") String any) {
            return any;
        }
    }

    similar annotation i have for trac-contoller endpoints as well.

    Below is my swagger config file

    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig{ 

        @Bean
        public Docket produceApi(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)    
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())    
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.demo.applications.trac.controller"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())       
        .build();
    }
    // Describe  apis
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
        .title("TRAC MicroService Rest APIs")
        .description("This page lists all the rest apis for TRAC MicroService.")
        .version("1.0-SNAPSHOT")    
        .build();
    }
    }

    Below is a Security config

    @Configuration
    class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {

                // -- swagger ui
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger.json",
                "/csrf",
                "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui",
                "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css",
                "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images",
                "/echo/**",            
                "/trac-service/**"

        };

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()       
                    .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**/*").denyAll();
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**","/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/css","/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/images");
        }

    }
```

Swagger ui is displaying properly in local (http)

But when i deployed it in AWS (https), the html format goes off. I tried many ways but not able to figure out why the html format goes off in AWS.

[image]

Comment: Does everything shows up correctly when you hit http://localhost:8080/your_context/swagger-ui.html? Please adjust this url according to your configuration.

Comment: Also, are you deploying to Elastic BeanStalk in AWS or are just running off an EC2 instance on your own app server/servlet container?

Comment: @Arun Patra , Everything shows up correctly when i hit local. I am deploying to  EC2 instance.  i am using docker file.

Comment: can you use the inspect feature in chrome and try finding out exactly which resources the browser is unable to  download?

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it Looks like your CSS / JS isn't loading. Please check your browser log to see what URL is used to make the request and setup the httpSecurity to allow those resources to load similar to your existing security roles.

Also Ensure below things.

1.swagger is configured something like below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

2.try to clean Chrome Web Browser cache.

Comment: You are right , the CSS/JS are not loading all the swagger css are failed to load.  below is the console output from browser,  Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:

Comment: for that please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734976/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-javascrip/41851906